# index for nested data couchbase

Tags: indexing, couchbase

Below is my Data

```
 {
      "VehicleTrip": {
           "departureTime": 1483176300000
      },
      "Orders": {
           "Order": [{
                "numberOfShops": 3,
                "customerTitle": "Mrs",
                "notes": ""
                "orderId": "3060_1"
           }, {
                "numberOfShops": 3,
                "customerTitle": "Mrs",
                "notes": ""
                "orderId": "3060_2"
           }]
      }
 }
```

I want to create index for orderId. My bucket name is Delivery

I tried with

```
CREATE INDEX isched1 
        ON `Delivery` (DISTINCT ARRAY v.orderId FOR v IN `Orders`.`Order` END);
```

But no use.
Can anyone help me in getting index for above data.

Thanks,
Vinay

Answer (score 0):

Your sample document has the `Orders` object at the same level as `VehicleTrip`, while your index treats as a property of `VehicleTrip`.

If you intended the nesting, your document should look like this

```
{
     "VehicleTrip": {
          "departureTime": 1483176300000
     },
     "Orders": {
          "Order": [
          {
               "numberOfShops": 3,
               "customerTitle": "Mrs",
               "notes": "",
               "orderId": "3060_1"
          }, {
               "numberOfShops": 3,
               "customerTitle": "Mrs",
               "notes": "",
               "orderId": "3060_2"
          }]
     }
}
```

Otherwise you'll need to update your index to match what's in your document:

```
CREATE INDEX isched1 
    ON `Delivery` (DISTINCT ARRAY v.orderId FOR v IN `Orders`.`Order` END);
```

Comment: I have created index using below
CREATE INDEX isched1 
        ON `Delivery` (DISTINCT ARRAY v.orderId FOR v IN `Orders`.`Order` END);

but still no use

Comment: @VinayJ, Check that the document is wellformed JSON.  The sample you provided requires a couple edits: commas after `notes` and a ']' to close out the `Order` array.